# Sharepoint File Not Found error

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, moss

I can't seem to find any relevant information on this exception. It seems to come and go on a specific site, any ideas?

```
[FileNotFoundException]: File Not Found.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPLocalFileInfo.get_CacheKey()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.GhostedFileTemplateInfo.get_CacheKey()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetFileCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(String virtualPath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CmsVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean& keyFromVPP)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
[HttpException]: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' was thrown.
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: An IIS reset can correct the problem but I'd like to put an end to it completely

Comment: Did you get these errors from the IIS logs? If not I might try there. GhostedFileTemplateInfo.get_CacheKey seems to me like it might be a file in the _layouts directory or a similar type of file that is on the filesystem.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731601/moss-404-errors-for-some-users-on-certain-sites-sometimes issue was related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [MOSS 404 errors for some users on certain sites, sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1731601/moss-404-errors-for-some-users-on-certain-sites-sometimes)

[FileNotFoundException]: File Not Found.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPLocalFileInfo.get_CacheKey()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.GhostedFileTemplateInfo.get_CacheKey()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetFileCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.EnsureCacheKeyAndViewStateHash(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPDatabaseFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(HttpContext context, SPRequestModuleData requestData)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualFile.GetVirtualPathProviderCacheKey(String virtualPath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.CmsVirtualPathProvider.GetCacheKey(String virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCacheKeyFro